# How I can convert .tflite model to a .pb frozen graph in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

At the beginning, I have the frozen graph .pb file of a model. I converted it to .tflite and post-training quantized this .tflite model. In the end, I would like to convert this quantized .tflite model into a .pb frozen graph. How can I achieve this last step?

I have searched a lot but didn't find any solutions or any hints. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try run toco with flags

```
toco --input_format=TFLITE --output_format=TENSORFLOW_GRAPHDEF ...
```

This may not work with some new operations of tflite

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My original tflite file works! But when I have my input tflite file to be a quantized file, it shows segmentation fault...

Comment: As far as I understand, this functionality of toco is not the main scenario of work, therefore it is poorly supported by developers.
Complement your problem with a sequence of commands that you performed, as well as a version of tensor flow. I'll try to figure it out

Comment: I figured out the segmentation fault problem. In the file tensorflow/lite/schema/schema_generated.h, inside function `inline flatbuffers::Offset<Tensor> CreateTensor`, if I replace `auto _shape = _o->shape.size() ? _fbb.CreateVector(_o->shape) : 0;` with `auto _shape =  _fbb.CreateVector(_o->shape);` The seg fault is gone. But another problem is that after conversion, the quantized model is dequantized...It goes back to its original size...Headache...

Comment: Yes, model's weights numbers are dequantized float32 numbers. But they are quantized to 255 values:)
What was your goal in back conversion?